# Ng-repeat orderBy date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to order the following by date:

```
<div class="inbox" ng-repeat="recipient in messages | orderBy: 'recipient':true">
<ul>
<div>
        <li class="inboxItem">
            <a ng-href="#/messaging/userChat/{{recipient.$id}}"><span> {{recipient.$id}} <br> </span></a>
            <div ng-repeat="content in recipient track by $index">
            <span ng-show="$last"> {{content.sender}} {{content.message}} <br> {{content.date}} <br></span>
            </div>
        </li>
</div>
</ul>
```

My data structure looks like that:

--ID: (recipient in ng-repeat)
-----Date (content in ng-repeat)
--------------Sender
--------------Message
--------------Date
-----Date (content in ng-repeat)
--------------Sender
--------------Message
--------------Date

Etc.

How do I order the list by the Date value? Why isn't my code working?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Date is in form of Date() form AngularJS.

I will be able to add better description of data later, for now I can provide a screenshot of Firebase set up.

[image]
Where 1375194092807517 is the USER ID of current user, 1384934715162092 is the USER ID of the one with whom the messages are sent.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? Particularly with the data structure.

Comment: I've actually answered my own question :) Thanks for your help anyways!!

Comment: Great, well done! \o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I figured it out myself. Since eveytime I send new message, I set LastUpdate to the Date() value, I user the following orderBy:

```
<div class="inbox" ng-repeat="recipient in messages | orderBy: 'LastUpdate':true">
```

This way I didn't needed to use orderBy nested ng-repeat :)

Thanks to every one who wanted to help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the build-in filter [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), as you did in the parent ng-repeat. The expression you provide could be a function in your scope

Comment: Could you explain what kind of function would you apply to the expression?

Comment: As soon as you provide a fiddle|plunker|codepen I will fork it an provide

Comment: Actually I figured it out myself: look at the answer on top :)